# How to get records of another table which are related to other table's element id and post?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to show payment table information  on payment page.

```
payments{student_id, course_id, payment_type_id}
students{id, name} 
courses{id, name} 
payment_types{id,name}
```

For the columns > course_id (in payment table) it is showing the names of courses in payment page.But for the other two columns it is not posting.Where is my mistake.Thank you in Advance!

Here is my **Payment.php** model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'student_id',
     'course_id',
     'payment_types_list_id',
];

protected $filter = [
   'page' => false,
   '_token' => false,
   'student_id' => '=',
   'course_id'  => '=',
   'payment_types_list_id' => '=',
];

public function Payment() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Payment');
}

public function course() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
}

public function students() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student');
}

public function PaymentType() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\PaymentType');
}
```

HERE IS **payments_table**

```
 public function up() {
      Schema::create('payments', function(Blueprint $table)
      {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned()->index();
          $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students');
          $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned()->index();
          $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
          $table->integer('payment_types_list_id');
          $table->foreign('payment_types_list_id')
                ->references('id')->on('payment_types_list');
          $table->timestamps();
      });
 }
```

Here is **PaymentController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $filter = $request->input();
        $sort = $request->query();
        $payments = Payment::filter($filter)->sort($sort)->paginate(10);
        foreach(PaymentType::all() as $payment_type) {
            $payment_types[$payment_type->id] = $payment_type->name;
        }
        foreach(Course::all() as $course) {
            $courses[$course->id] = $course->name;
        }
        foreach(Student::all() as $student) {
            $students[$student->id] = $student->name;
        }
        return view('payments.index', compact('payments', 'filter','courses','students', 'payment_types'));
    }
```

And here is **Payment/index.php**

```
@forelse ($payments as $key => $payment)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
      <td>{{ $payment->student['name'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ $payment->course['name']}}</td>
      <td>{{$payment->payment_types_list['name']}}</td> 
   </tr> 
@endforelse
```

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: It is not giving any error, it is just not showing the students names and payment_types to the view, only course names are shown.

Comment: @AmitGupta thanks for your reply. Where do you think problem could be,I am over this for 4 days ))))

Comment: Doesn't a `forelse` need an `empty` bit as well?

Comment: @apokryfos yeah  you are right/there should be. Actually i have it in my code, But i forgot to write here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is with the name of the relation. When you define a relation then it should be accessed with the same defined name.

For example -

If your relation name is `PaymentType` then you should access the relation as:

```
{{ $payment->PaymentType->name }}
```

OR

```
{{ $payment->PaymentType['name'] }}
```

And for student relation, it should be `belongsTo` not `belongsToMany` so -

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
}
```

Then you can access it as:

```
{{ $payment->student->name }}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Yeah,, You are right my mistake was student not students and in that model with the name and relationship ... THANK YOU VERY MUCH.